# Apply both open and close state to same button?

Tags: jquery, css

I'm a jQuery beginner.

Trying to apply a close state to same hamburger button w/ an open state already applied.

I'm able to click the hamburger button and reveal the slide-out navigation, but when duplicating the button and applying the close state, it doesn't seem to wanna work.

I'm following this article: http://css-tricks.com/off-canvas-menu-with-css-target/

Here is my codepen:
http://codepen.io/Goatsy/pen/mBqku

```
  <a href="#main-nav" class="open-menu">
<button>
    <span class="line line-t"></span>
    <span class="line line-m"></span>
    <span class="line line-b"></span>
</button>
  </a>  


  <a href="#" class="close-menu">
<button>
    <span class="line line-t"></span>
    <span class="line line-m"></span>
    <span class="line line-b"></span>
</button>
  </a>
```

Update: 
I added what I'm hoping is the right toggle function.
Now the nav is disappearing. I want the nav to close when clicking the X. And the nav to open when clicking the hamburger.

```
$("button").on("click",function(){
  $(this).toggleClass("menu-on");
});


$( "button" ).click(function() {
  $( "nav" ).toggle( );
});
```

Comment: This is not a jQuery question. The demo you are using is pure CSS. Your CodePen entry is missing the `header` element that has the swapping `open-menu` / `close-menu` element that is performing all the work.

Comment: Do you want to hide div containing  "This Little Piggy Went To Market" text? on close button click?

Comment: Toggle some class on `nav` as well. :target is not much use for toggle logic.

Comment: @ShankerPaudel I want the nav to close when clicking the X. And the nav to open when clicking the hamburger.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `.toggle` function, and [here](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) is a tutorial about how to use it.

For example, if you want to toggle show and hide for div with id bar:

```
$("button").click(function() {
  $('#bar').toggle(function() {
    $(this).show(1000);
  }, function() {
    $(this).hide(1000);
  });
});
```